# R - Weird behavior of grepl

Tags: r

I want to know if there is a certain string contained in another string. This works fine here:

```
grepl("a","a")
```

However, what I actually want to test is the following and this one doesn't work:

```
grepl("is.na(x)","is.na(x)")
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: add `fixed = TRUE` in your `grepl`

Comment: If it is fixed comparison, then why not use `==`, rather than `grepl`

Comment: @akrun the string could be longer?!

Comment: @drmariod  In that case,`fixed = TRUE` will also return `FALSE` i.e. `grepl("is.na(x) ss","is.na(x)", fixed = TRUE)
[1] FALSE`

Comment: @akrun i guess `grepl("is.na(x)","is.na(x) ss", fixed = TRUE) [1] TRUE` this would be the real scenario

Comment: @joel.wilson Yes, you may be right

Comment: joel.wilson is right. Thanks for the comments. This solves my problem. I'm relatively new to stack overflow - why didnt you "answer" the question, so it can be upvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the special characters like this:

```
 grepl("is\\.na\\(x\\)","is.na(x)")
 [1] TRUE
```